# Max.math for this function - Homework

Tags: javascript

Create an html page, add 3 text boxes in which the user will input 3 numbers :a,b,c

Add a button that, on click, will calculate the maximum number of the three. The result will be displayed in an alert. The program should not crash if the user does not input one or two numbers.

**Cases**:

- If no number is introduced then a message should be displayed asking the user to input at least on number.
- If only one number of the three is introduced, that number is the maximum number.
- If two numbers are introduced then it should be displayed the maximum of the two.
- If three numbers are introduced then it should be displayed the maximum of the three.

I started like this:

```js
function displaysubmit() {
    var numarA = document.getElementById("numarA").value;
    var numarB = document.getElementById("numarB").value;
    var numarC = document.getElementById("numarC").value;

    var numarAAsNumber = parseInt(numarA);
    var numarBAsNumber = parseInt(numarB);
    var numarCAsNumber = parseInt(numarC);

   
    if (!isNaN(numarAAsNumber) && !isNaN(numarBAsNumber) && !isNaN(numarCAsNumber)) {
        var Submit = Math.max(numarA, numarB, numarC);
        alert(Submit);

    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Exercitiul2</title>
        <script src="exercitiul2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>a</label>
        <input type="text" id="numarA" />

        <label>b</label>
        <input type="text" id="numarB" />

        <label>c</label>
        <input type="text" id="numarC" />

        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't know how start to write in script. Please help me.

Comment: Could you show me the javascript file?

Comment: I'm a beginner. I started from 0. I have to write it in the simplest terms.

Comment: So should I write what the javacript file should be?

Comment: yes, that's what you should. i would be very helpful

Comment: Please know that when asking about homework it is a _must_ that you have _tried something first_. It won't help you understand or learn if we just straight up write the solution for you.

Comment: I tried several approaches, it didn't work, I deleted everything because I got angry

Comment: Hint: Select the elements by ```document.getElementById("numarA").innerHTML```. When left blank, it'll be ```""```, and if you put it in any ```if``` statement it will return false e.g. ```if (document.getElementById("numarA").innerHTML) {\\dosomething}``` won't do anything.

Comment: You need to show what you heaved tried, SO is not free Homework code writing service, but we will gladly help with fixing the code.

Comment: I would suggest you to start from a tutorial, like this  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-an-html-calculator-app-from-scratch-using-javascript-4454b8714b98/

Comment: You might want to use Ctrl+Z to recover your code.

Comment: Here are your tasks: 1. add on-click function
2. get values of inputs inside function
3. Search how to find out maximum number  You have all this answered here on SO and https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: I posted and extension js

Answer (score 1):

You did good just missing some basics;

1 - Wrap your inputs and submit button in form

2 - Add on-click function to button

3 - Pass event into function

4 - prevent form from submitting/reloading using that event

5 - You do not need to add parse int, you can make your inputs `type="number"` instead

6 - in if statement check if all 3 fields are empty then display message, if not calculate the submit

Example:

```js
function displaysubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var numarA = document.getElementById("numarA").value;
  var numarB = document.getElementById("numarB").value;
  var numarC = document.getElementById("numarC").value;

  if (numarA === "" && numarB === "" && numarC === "") {
    alert("Enter at least one number");
  } else {
    var Submit = Math.max(numarA, numarB, numarC);
    alert(Submit);
  }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Exercitiul2</title>
  <script src="exercitiul2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label>a</label>
    <input type="number" id="numarA" />

    <label>b</label>
    <input type="number" id="numarB" />

    <label>c</label>
    <input type="number" id="numarC" />

    <button id="submit" onclick="displaysubmit(event)">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but I do not know how to add that at first to do this: If no number is introduced then a message should be displayed asking the user to input at least on number.

Comment: @TomițăIvanov Sorry missed that part. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint:

Select the elements by

```js
document.getElementById("numarA").innerHTML
```

When left blank, it'll be `""`, and if you put it in any `if` statement it will return false e.g.

```js
if (document.getElementById("numarA").innerHTML) {
someFunction();
}
```

won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the button click event?

do
`<button id="submit" onclick="displaysubmit()">Submit</button>`